# Is it possible to show file output on desktop background?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Maybe this question a little bit strange, but i want to understand is it possible to show file output like

> tail -f file.log

on windows desktop background?

I saw something like this feature in video player, where video embedded to background on windows desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/cms/) and the "[Low-overhead Multi-file Tail plugin for Rainmeter](http://www.wizardstower.co.uk/wordpress/2011/03/13/low-overhead-multi-file-tail-plugin-for-rainmeter/)":

[image]

Comment: System.FormatException fall when i try to tail file, can you help

Comment: it looks like that this plugin works incorrect with lattest versions of Rainmeter

Comment: yes, comments on that plugin page suggest that the plugin does not work on the latest. suggestion: contact and pester the author. suggestion2: use an older version of rainmeter.

Comment: ok, i already wrote a comment uneder his post

Comment: author said that i possibly works in ver. 2.0 but it also not work

Comment: then pester pester pester. with enough "pressure" folks move. :)

Comment: ha ha, "pleeeease pleaseeee, do it asap" ^)))